# Can you "remember" what link is clicked on a webpage?

Tags: c#, html, css, hyperlink

I'm working in Visual Studios to create a website for a movie theater (for class) I'm wondering if there's a way to "remember" what link is clicked for a show time? I know I could just create a webpage for each time, but I'd rather track an id, if that's possible!

By clicking the link, they'll go to the right page, but is there any way for me to put into the system what time they clicked? I couldn't find any similar questions here.

Comment: Is this MVC?  is it a link to an action on a controller?  if so, just add some parameters to the link and pick them up in the controller action...  if not, then could you show us the code where you build the links and give us a little more detail about your system's architecture?

Comment: I don't believe so, I'm using WebForms and Masterpages - this class is focusing on CSS, so I don't need an extremely technical solution, just something so I can output the time to the user at the end.As for the code, it's just an anchor to the ticketing page where the user can choose what type/how many tickets. ie: <a href="ticketing.aspx">7:15</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use sessions to hold the showtime selected. create an LinkButton with an onCommand that creates a session before redirecting them to the seating chart or checkout page.

so say a user is on your movie page and the user selects the 12pm showtime. When the user clicks on the link, it will run what ever is in your code behind. You can create a Session["DateTime"] and set it to the value of the linkbutton. then, redirect to the seating page.

on the seating page, you can check if there's a session. if it finds one, then you can load the seating chart or purchasing page. if it does not find one, you might want to redirect them back to select a time.

HTML example:

```
<h2>Next Big Movie</h2>
<asp:LinkButton  id="lbNBM12pm" runat="server" OnCommand="lb_Click" text="12:00pm"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Code Behind example:

```
protected void lb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string time = (sender as LinkButton).Text;
    Session["TimeSelected"] = time;
    Response.Redirect("/nextstep.aspx");
}
```

and on the next page, you'll read what was passed over in the page load and set the Selected Movie time text:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(Session["TimeSelected"] != null)
        {
            MovieTime.Text = Session["TimeSelected"].ToString();

        }
            else
{
//user did not select a time
//possibly redirect them back to the showtimes page.
  response.redirect("/previousepage.aspx");
}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tested this yet, but this looks like what I was looking for!

Comment: awesome! let me know if you need any more help! also please mark the response as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly. First, create a table with the following columns:

```
create table Links
(
 id int identity,
 link varchar(100),
 timeclicked datetime
)
```

then fire an ajax or a simple HTML POST request to submit what link is clicked in a spefic time.